# Concatenate arrays by column in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, concatenation

I have a list of arrays, where each array is a list of lists.  I want to turn this into a single array with all the columns.  I've tried using for loops to get this done, but it feels like it should be doable in list comprehension.  Is there a nice one-liner that will do this?

```py
    Example Input: [[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],[[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]]]
    
    Desired Output: [[1,2,7,8],[3,4,9,10],[5,6,11,12]]
```

Note: Example only has two arrays in the main list, but my actual data has much more, so I'm looking for something that works for N subarrays.

Edit:
Example trying to solve this

Works for two but doesn't generalize:

```
[input[0][i]+input[1][i] for i in range(len(input[0]))]
```

These don't work, but show the idea:

```
[[element for table in input for element in row] for row in table]
[[*imput[j][i] for j in range(len(input))] for i in range(len(input[0]))]
```

Edit: Selected answer that uses only list comprehension and zip, but all answers (as of now) work, so use whichever fits your style/use case best.

Comment: Do you want list or numpy array as the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generalize this from the standard [list flattening pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> L = [[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],[[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]]]
>>> list([y for z in x for y in z] for x in zip(*L))
[[1, 2, 7, 8], [3, 4, 9, 10], [5, 6, 11, 12]]
>>> L = [[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],[[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]],[[13,14],[15,16],[17,18]]]
>>> list([y for z in x for y in z] for x in zip(*L))
[[1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 14], [3, 4, 9, 10, 15, 16], [5, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way of doing it:

```py
initial = [[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],[[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]]]
output = [a+b for a, b in zip(*initial)]

print(output)
```

If you have more lists, this also works:

```py
import itertools

initial = [[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],[[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]],[[13,14],[15,16],[17,18]]]
output = [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(values)) for values in zip(*initial)]

print(output)
```

Comment: I like the idea of using zip, I didn't think of that.  This appears to only work for two arrays in the list.  Is there a way to generalize it?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind it is a tuple in the list.You could also try:

```
from itertools import chain
a = [[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [[7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]], [[13, 14], [15, 16], [17, 18]]]
output = list(map(list, map(chain.from_iterable, zip(*a))))

# [[1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 14], [3, 4, 9, 10, 15, 16], [5, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This would do it, I named your input `first`:

```
[*map(lambda x: list(i for s in x for i in s), zip(*first))]
```

```
[[1, 2, 7, 8], [3, 4, 9, 10], [5, 6, 11, 12]]
```